# Which file that designer sends to developer in React Native

Tags: react-native, native

I am going to do a react native project for both android and IOS. 
I have done a desktop app by reactJS but i haven't had any experience about react native. Now my team has some designers (HTML, CSS, Photoshop), so i wonder that what kind of file should they send to developers? HTML, CSS files? or anything else? I've searched by google, i see that mobile app devs also use Zeplin tool, but i'm not sure that Zeplin is good for native app.
Please let me know some options to deal with it, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React Native uses JavaScript for styling. There is a predefined set of key-value pairs which allow you to style the different components used in React Native. Those properties and their values are based on CSS, but there are some important differences.

It is probably a good idea to define the design in CSS, but the designers should be aware of the differences. For instance: a modified version of Flexbox is supported, but the newer CSS Grid API is not.